# Ubuntu apps crashing in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, crash

Basically, I have had a number of applications on my computer crashing, such as Wine Applications, CompizConfig Settings Manager, and Caffeine. I tried running them in terminal, and even re-installing CompizConfig to see if it fixed the problem, but it didn't. I also noticed, when I ran CompizConfig in Terminal, I got an output that said "Segmentation fault (Core dumped)", is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System errors may be depended from hardware I think. 
I had in past on my Dell Vostro 3560 Ubuntu 12.04 , and on pure system after fresh install I had system errors. Similar situation is on 14.04, but now it's really rare behaviour.

Comment: I once before had problems, I thought it was my Hard Drive, even somebody said it was failing, after re-installing everything was fine until 1 month later I get this problem, could replacing the Hard Drive fix the problem (Note: I got the PC in 2012, it is usually on 24/7, and I run a Gaming Server while the PC is on, that constantly accesses the hard drive, could this be the problem?)

Answer (score 0):

If the system is stable in general, that could be individual problems with the applications.

The problems may still be related somehow, like that they are using a common library or subsystem that is somehow broken.

In general, it is often useful to try starting misbehaving applications with an empty user configuration.
That can be done by logging in as a new user, or renaming (or deleting) the configuration files of the program.

Also, take a look at the file `/var/log/syslog` for obvious problems.

If you can list error messages of other failing applications, that would give some hints.